# Free Hex Editor that allows search and replace across files in folders and their subfolders etc

Tags: hex, hex-editors

Looking for something like Neo Hex editor Pro and above but free that allows to replace hex, string etc. values across multiple files in folders and their sub-folders.

Anything out there?

Answer (score 3):

The `find` and `sed` tools can be combined to do some of this task, though they won't be very helpful if you're "feeling your way through the changes" -- you have to know exactly what you want when you invoke them.

If you wanted to change `0xDEADBEEF` to `0xCAFEBABE` in an entire project, you could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*pattern*' -exec sed -i -e 's/\xDE\xEA\xBE\xEF/\xCA\xFE\xBA\xBE/g' {} \;
```

Both `find(1)` and `sed(1)` are incredibly flexible; the time spent learning them both will be handsomely repaid.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Windows editor is psPad, which includes a hex editor. It can find in files... and someone [posted a bug](http://pspad.nlift.com/issues/71/hex-search/) a couple years ago about when searching in a hex file, psPad was ignoring the null byte, 00.

I tried it out and you'll need to paste in the ascii characters representing the pattern you seek. Searching on 'a' in the c:\php folder got interesting results:
[image: screen capture of psPad searching hex files]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 4 years late, but PowerGrep for windows does what you are looking for.  I hope this can help others as I had exactly this problem today.

[Link to page showing binary search](https://www.powergrep.com/binaryfiles.html) will show you how to do this.
Basically what you need to do is open powergrep gui, whilst a confusing array of options, on the fight pane you can see Search Type:"Simple Search" -> "Search and Replace".  After this change Search Type:"Literal Text" -> "Binary Data" and on the left pane choose File Formats: "Proprietary format..." -> "none"

[image: Example showing simple search and replace]